# Capacitors in Series and Parallel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance

I'm working on a physics project and we're disagreeing on how to analyze a circuit. I think the circuit should be $(1/c_1 + 1/c_2)^{-1} + c_3$ and other people in my group think it should be $((c_3 + c_1)^{-1} + 1/c_2)^{-1}$. Who's correct?

[image: diagram of the circuit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. The second expression would work for the following diagram:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was right since it was more consistent with our results, but I didn't want to fight it since I was the only one in the group with that opinion.